# Xpath not valid with Selenium Webdriver "Xpath not found"

Tags: javascript, vba, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am using the Selenium WebDriver for VBA to get some information from a website, 
but first I need to select a "category" and click a button, no problem i've been doing that a few times, but on this website the XPath does not return a valid object.

I suspect the website is a "dynamic format" and it breaks the XPath

How do I navigate to the button and click it when it's path is not valid?

Line of code that is not working:
driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id=""buttonBar""]/td").Click

website:
http://www.ocepar.org.br/ocepar/cooperativasPR/consultaPorRamo.html

The button is the "continuar" on the botton of the page

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to set the context on the frame to access the button:

```vb
Dim driver As New FirefoxDriver
driver.Get "http://www.ocepar.org.br/ocepar/cooperativasPR/consultaPorRamo.html"
driver.SwitchToFrame "buttons"
driver.FindElementById("buttonBar").Click
```